# How to preselect a value in Listbox at page load?

Tags: javascript

I have this simplified `self.jsp` form:

```
<form name="count" action="self.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="data1" id="data1" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="text" name="data2" id="data2" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="text" name="data3" id="data3" maxlength="50"/>
    <button id="recalc" type="submit" value="recalc">Recalculate</button>
    <button id="save" type="submit" value="save">Save to Database</button>
</form>
```

Now, I want to automatically submit this form at the page loading using javascript. I want to do some field pre-populating. The problem here is that I have more than one button to "submit" the form. So I can't use the js that ask the form to submit itself (like `document.getElementById("count").submit();`) because I wouldn't be able to know which button get pressed. But I seems to not able to use the javascript to "push" the button using code `document.getElementById("recalc").submit();`. The question is:

1. What is the javascript code if I want to "automatically run" the "recalc" button?
2. What is the javascript code if I want to "automatically run" the "save" button?
3. Is there any mistake in my html form code? For example, is it impossible to have two "submit" button at one form? Or is to "push" the button, I can't use `submit()` function, but another function, for example, `click()` maybe?

I'm just a beginner at javascript. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update:

I'm trying to have two button at one form. The recalculate button is to recalculate the value at data3 using the information data1 and data2. The save button is to save all the data1, data2, and data3 to database. All of the required java code is put before the form. You can see that the form is referring to itself. So if the recalculate is pressed, the form is only reload itself, but now with the data3 is prepopulated. If the save is pressed, the form is reload itself, but with all the data1, data2, and data3 is saved onto the database. But I want to be able to push the button using javascript, and I don't know how to trigger the button click. I can only trigger the form submission using javascript, hence the problem is I don't know which button was pressed or will be send onto the form itself. Sure I can check using the names at the JSP code, but how if I want to say "the button pressed was recalc button", or "the button pressed was save button" to the JSP that will receive the form data? So that's why I need to trigger the button individually. Or can't I?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Both buttons are submit buttons, so both will submit the form if pressed by a user. If you give the buttons a name, then the one that is used to submit the form will have its name and value also submitted, the one that wasn't pressed wont. It's not clear how the recalc button recalcuates the form without submitting it, perhaps you need a plain button (`<button type="button"...>`) with script to do the calculation.

Comment: I'm trying to have two button at one form. The recalculate button is to recalculate the value at data3 using the information data1 and data2. The save button is to save all the data1, data2, and data3 to database. All of the required java code is put before the form. You can see that the form is referring to itself. So if the recalculate is pressed, the form is only reload itself, but now with the data3 is prepopulated. If the save is pressed, the form is reload itself, but with all the data1, data2, and data3 is saved onto the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for Q1: document.getElementById('recalc').click();

A for Q2: document.getElementById('save').click();

A for Q3: You can have several submit buttons in a form, but you need to add "name" attribute to those submit buttons (name/value pair), so the server side would be able to know which button was pressed.

Hope these helps

Comment: It works! I was trying to use trigger('click') but then realized it was for jQuery. Orang Indo juga rupanya ya. :D thanks for the help.